# Why the button can not show the data, when is running the button got showing out but when click it is no fuction

Tags: python, ipywidgets

```
import nltk
from nltk.chat.util import Chat, reflections
import pandas as pd
import ipywidgets as widgets
from ipywidgets import interact, interact_manual,fixed

df = pd.read_excel (r'C:\Users\Desktop\ex\ex_dataset.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet3')

print ('Travel Suggestion')

pairs=[
   ['My name is (.*)',['hi %1']],
   ['What is Travel Suggestion',['Travel Suggestion is suggest the best of Restaurant or Tourist attraction']],
   
]

widgets.interact_manual.opts['manual_name'] = 'Restaurant'
def Restaurant():
    print(df)
    
interact_manual(Restaurant)
chat = Chat(pairs,reflections)
chat.converse()
```

Comment: Are you running jupyter-notebook? jupyter-lab?

Comment: Ya, I am using jupyter-notebook to doing the chatbot.

Comment: But the button can not print the data out.

Comment: Try commenting the last line and loading it in the next cell

Comment: mean is like this?
In[]:  interact_manual(Res)
       chat = Chat(pairs,reflections)
       chat.converse()

But still can't display the data

Comment: Can add the print(df) in the pairs , For example, pairs=[ ['What is the price',[print(df]  ], get the data and in the pairs. but I do like this got error. Got any suggestions to do this?

Comment: By the time `chat.converse()` is running, you __can not__ run anything else. Therefore, finish your cell with `chat = Chat(pairs,reflections)` and in the next notebook cell, place the `chat.converse()`. Hopefully, that's ok with you

Comment: Thank you aerijman to explain to me of the problem, follow your explanation can display the data.

Comment: Cool. Since it helped, I will add it as an answer for others in the future.

Comment: Can I ask about the pairs, in the pairs I can't add the print(df), example pairs =[ [['What is the description of Beta KL',['Robot:' print(df)]],

Comment: No need to hard code inside the data. using the print to display the data from excel.

Comment: because need answer user question data, like user ask[' What is the description of the thing','Robot:'print(df)] to print the specified data, no all data from excel

Comment: According to [source](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/chat/util.html#Chat) that is not possible as `pairs` should be a tuple of __patterns__ and __responses__.

Comment: You can print df into string and use it as response.

Comment: Inside df data all are string string , can I know the response work?

Comment: Can you accept this answer and open another question with your _second question_? Even if my answer is not the optimal, someone else could provide a better option.

Answer (score 0):

By the time `chat.converse()` is running, you **can not** run anything else in the notebook.

Here is a workaround that should fit your needs:

*cell[1]*:

```
import nltk
from nltk.chat.util import Chat, reflections
import pandas as pd
import ipywidgets as widgets
from ipywidgets import interact, interact_manual,fixed

df = pd.read_excel (r'C:\Users\Desktop\ex\ex_dataset.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet3')

print ('Travel Suggestion')

pairs=[
   ['My name is (.*)',['hi %1']],
   ['What is Travel Suggestion',['Travel Suggestion is suggest the best of Restaurant or Tourist attraction']],
   
]

widgets.interact_manual.opts['manual_name'] = 'Restaurant'
def Restaurant():
    print(df)
    
interact_manual(Restaurant)
chat = Chat(pairs,reflections)
```

*cell[2]*:

```
chat.converse()
```